# Laravel dynamically row - Set value into specific element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Morning,
I have form with dynamically rows and select option into first column.
I would like to set a value into specific element of my row after event select.
Actually for each row, all elements change after select.

My form:

```
 <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>
         <Select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="item_desc[]" id="item_desc" type="integer" onchange="select_field(this)">
           <option> </option>
            @foreach ($articles as $article)
              <option>{{$article->id}}</option>
            @endforeach
          </Select>
         </td>
         <td class="writefields" name="item_fields[]"></td>
         <td class="writenature"></td>
         <td class="writeuom"></td>
         <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="integer" name="item_quantity[]"></td>
         <td><i class="btn far fa-trash-alt" onclick="remove_row(this)"></i></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
```

My JQuery Code :

```
function select_field(e)
{
  ...,
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/achats/selection",
        data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, code_item : selection },
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (data) {
            $('.writefields').text(data.UoM);
            $('.writeuom').text(data.UoM);
            $('.writenature').text(data.NatureAChat);
        }
    });
}
```

Thks for your helps !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you need something similar to this in order to target the specific row which has changed.

```js
function select_field(e) {
  let test = 'test';

  $(e).parents('tr').find('.writefields').text(test);
  $(e).parents('tr').find('.writeuom').text(test);
  $(e).parents('tr').find('.writenature').text(test);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="item_desc[]" id="item_desc" type="integer" onchange="select_field(this)">
          <option>Select an option</option>
          <option value="1">Item 1</option>
          <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="writefields" name="item_fields[]"></td>
      <td class="writenature"></td>
      <td class="writeuom"></td>
      <td><input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="integer" name="item_quantity[]"></td>
      <td><i class="btn far fa-trash-alt" onclick="remove_row(this)"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Exactly what i need... thks for yur help !